# Google analytics funnel required steps

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking, goals

I have created a goal in GA which tracks when someone visits the signup page for an application - it works fine.

However, in itself that doesn't really help as I want to know if they actually sign up so I created a new goal to the application home page with a required step of the signup page as below:

[image]

The problem is that when I look at my Goal URL's for example it is showing the wrong number - it shows 792 created accounts today when, in fact there were 8.

Further when I look at Reverse Goal path and filter to the exact URL for the application, it shows me 778 where the Goal Previous Step 1 was (entrance) and Step 2 and 3 are (not set). I assume this means they did not visit the signup page hence they shouldn't trigger the goal.

I only want the goal to register if they go to /signup and then go to /application - if they arrive at /application any other way then it should not register.

Have I set this up correctly and can I do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Visiting a Sign Up Page and Creating an Account is not really the same thing. Have you thought about setting up a 3rd page where the user will be redirected to after they finish signing up for the account? That will give you the right numbers.

Step 1 - User Goes to /application

Step 2 - User Goes from /application to Sign Up page

Step 3 - User is Redirected to a confirmation page after the account is created

So if 100 people went to Step 1 and from there 50 visited the Sign Up page and 5 of them created an account...your conversion rate is 5%.

You can also setup additions steps to track form abandonment rate if your form is long.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do above - the user goes to /signup to create an account but that, in itself, does not mean they actually signed up however once they do signup they then are redirected to /application. The problem is existing members go to /application hence why I thought the funnel would only show me those who went to /signup and then went to /application but it is not. I do not want to add another page to the signup process though I guess I could add a url parameter which is only set on first login after signup but I don't think I should have to with funnels

Comment: Got it. Well then why don't you setup you funnel in reverse? Sign Up Page to Application. I assume that your registered users would not be visiting the sign up form. Still, the only way to make sure that the numbers are accurate is by adding a page that only users that just registered can visit.

Comment: I had assumed that the ultimate destination (/application) went into destination and then the steps leading there into funnel - is it the other way around?